# I've already installed micro-cors, and when I attempted to build, I got the following result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I encountered the following issue while constructing the Next.js Stripe project and I apologize.

```
./src/pages/api/webhooks.ts:3:18
Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'micro-cors'. 'E:/Project/longlifecoin/node_modules/micro-cors/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

  1 | import Stripe from 'stripe';
  2 | import { buffer } from 'micro';
> 3 | import Cors from 'micro-cors';
```

I don't know what is causing this error.
Would be grateful if you could help me out.

I'm crossing my fingers that I can build this project without any issues.
Please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, should be lowercase? `import cors from 'micro-cors`. That's based on what I see in the [docs ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micro-cors#usage). Only that's showing with **CommonJS**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install `yarn add @types/micro-cors` or `npm i @types/micro-cors`

As a last resort, You can add // @ts-ignore to the line above to ignore any type-checking issues.

Answer (score 2):

`npm i -D @types/micro-cors`.

It's a TS error that's common for many packages. TS can't find the **types** that it needs to do its job.

Depending on your settings in your editor, you should be able to get realtime feedback on those types of things along with appropriate suggestions too.

Comment: I didn't install npm.

Comment: . Well you used some type of **package manager.** `npm` is the default for Node. So, maybe you used `yarn` or `pnpm`?

Comment:  Is that supposed to be for this ❔? Seems to be about `stripe`? Also, **generally** avoid `:any`? At the least maybe use `unknown` as `any` just makes TS kind of pointless.

Comment: Please help me against above image issue.

Comment: I've still need your help.

Comment: If all else fails, you can add // @ts-ignore to the line above to ignore any type-checking issues.

Comment: Oof. Yeah, but again, defeating the purpose of TS. Maybe don't use TS and just try to get this working in straight JS @LillianCarr?

Answer (score 2):

install the required types for `micro-cors`

```
npm install --save-dev @types/micro-cors
```